# need to decode gzip application/octet-stream pcap data

Tags: decode, pcap

I am trying to decode the data from a winpcap file, I have uploaded it on the link please help me.

I tried everything but it seems I am unable to decode the response data to readable digits.

http://pcapperf.appspot.com/view?hash_str=0ba390ad10bd162ec264ec083b1a7fd1

Comment: There is no pcap to download, only HAR. From the pcap you should get the data without problems with wireshark.

Comment: i have it but it is not in the form of readable data..this is link to pcap file https://www.dropbox.com/s/whr43d4v23fudsh/2014_02_05_234051.pcap

Comment: i can see the data in getworldrecord command but its not in readable form but it is encrypted. i dont know how to decode it to a readable form.

Comment: actually i m trying to decode a file that i get from this api request

http://api.bikes.cmdragracing.com/?task=getWorldRecord&version=12&world_records&level=3&distance=200&vehicle=15

Comment: They seem to use an application specific encoding, e.g. decoding is outside of HTTP. And its also not gzip encoded (there is not Content-Encoding: gzip header).